# Batch script: how to read file with spaces in for loop

Tags: batch-file, filenames, spaces

How to read filename with spaces ,

Bascially a folder will contain same file name with different extension, I want to delete one of the file with extension .csv.completed.

eg

```
abc t1.xlsx
abc t1.csv.completed
```

following code is not working its giving message.... 
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\"*.xlsx".

script

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq delims==" %%I in ("C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx") do (
    if exist "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\%%~nl.completed" del %%I
)
```

Comment: `del "%%I"` ...

Comment: You have a typo here: `%%~nl`.  That should be: `%%~nI`

Comment: again getting message.... The system cannot find the file C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx. Changed %%~nl to %%~n & captial I

Comment: There is a slash missing after `des_cp`.

Comment: You are also missing the csv extension in your code: `%%~nI.csv.completed`

Comment: The system cannot find the file C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx.

Comment: latest script  @echo off

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx") do (
    if exist "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\%%~nI.csv.completed" del "%%I"
)

Comment: @Sbanga, what didn't you understand about the slash is missing after the directory name `des_cp`?

Comment: in my script its there, why its not showing here dont know. I have tried without /F also as suggest by Stephan. But still its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work.

```
@echo off

for %%I in ("C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx") do (
    if exist "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\%%~nI.csv.completed" del "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\%%~nxI"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

`for /f` processes the *content* of a file. To process *files* (filenames), use a plain `for`:

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx") do echo %%I
```

Comment: its not working... message i am getting The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp>for %I in ("C:\Users\demo\demo\des_cp\*.xlsx") do

Comment: Is there anything after `do`? And shouldn't there be a `\` between `des_xp` and `*.xlsx`?

Comment: yes for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\*.xlsx") do (
    if exist "C:\Users\demo\Desktop\des_cp\%%~nI.completed" del "%%I"
)

Comment: @Sbanga, he just told you not to use a `FOR /F` or its options.